# Java AWT controls issue

Tags: java, awt

I'd like to create a calculator using Java AWT library, however I'm having problems putting a label and a textfield on the same row. Also, everything is mixing up. When I run the program, at first it shows 2 labels and 2 textfields on the same row, but if I resize it, the labels, buttons & textfields are one on top of another. Could you please help me?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public  class Calculator extends Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame= new Frame();
        frame.setTitle("Mini Calculator App");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300,300);

        LayoutManager gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        frame.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        Label firstNumber = new Label("Add a number");
        frame.add(firstNumber);

        TextField numar1 = new TextField();
        frame.add(numar1);

        Label secondNumber = new Label("Add another number");
        frame.add(secondNumber);

        TextField numar2 = new TextField();
        frame.add(numar2);

        Choice operatie = new Choice();
        operatie.add("+"); operatie.add("-");
        operatie.add("*"); operatie.add("/");
        frame.add(operatie);

        Button calcul = new Button("Calculate");
        frame.add(calcul);

        Label result = new Label("Result is");
        frame.add(result);

        GridBagConstraints afisare;

        afisare = new GridBagConstraints();
        afisare.gridx = 0;
        afisare.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(firstNumber, afisare);

        afisare = new GridBagConstraints();
        afisare.gridx = 0;
        afisare.gridy = 1;
        afisare.gridwidth = 10;
        afisare.gridheight = 10;
        frame.add(numar1, afisare);

        afisare = new GridBagConstraints();
        afisare.gridx = 1;
        afisare.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(secondNumber, afisare);

        afisare = new GridBagConstraints();
        afisare.gridx = 1;
        afisare.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(numar2, afisare);

        afisare = new GridBagConstraints();
        afisare.gridx = 2;
        afisare.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(operatie, afisare);

        afisare = new GridBagConstraints();
        afisare.gridx = 4;
        afisare.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(result, afisare);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYm8b.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5CGj.png)

Comment: *I'd like to create a calculator using Java AWT library* Don't - that's an absolute dinosaur ;)

Comment: 1) Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. 2) You should invoke pack() BEFORE making the frame visible, so all the components are displayed at their preferred size. 3) Use Swing not AWT. Swing components start with "J". 4) Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information and examples. The `GridBagLayout` will show you how to better structure your class. 5) Don't use multiple add(...) statements for each component. The component should be added with a constraint the first time.